# enum binding source not avalible c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, enums

How to bind enum to ListBox in WPF App if `enum` not available in the `<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type sys:???}">`?

I saw template [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613576(v=vs.110).aspx)

How to solve this problem? Thank you everyone.

Comment: What do you mean by "if enum not available"?
Do you have any sample code to show us (not the template from the MSDN, but your code that isn't working)?

Comment: I use: <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type sys:???}"> after sys: enum not available

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the correct references at the top of your XAML file.

For example, from that link you provided:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

If you are using your own custom assembly, then you need to reference the given namespace and file. Intellisense should help you with entry you need I believe.

Comment: I did it,  VS2013 reinstalled  did not help

Comment: availabely public struct only (DateTime, IntXX and so on), Enum, Math (public class) not availible

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. You must manually write "Enum" after "sys:". Intellisens does not offer this value in the drop-down list.